# Angular 6 Bootstrap 4 have to click twice on menu tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mat-tab

I have to click on the following menu "Text View" tab (mat-tab-link) twice to get the router-outlet to become active and underline the tab.  I know this because of the documents.component.html content for the radio buttons, in it does not become active, unless I click twice on the Text View tab.  Then the "Option 4" button shows active, and the tab underlines.

**documents-pane.component.html**

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar aria-label="documentsTabs">
  <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/customApp']">CustomApp</a>
  <a mat-tab-link 
    *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
    [routerLink]="link.path"
    routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive"
    skipLocationChange>
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**documents-pane.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomAppDocumentsComponent } from './documents/documents.component';
import { CustomAppGridComponent } from './grid/grid.component';
import { CustomAppSearchComponent } from './customApp-search/customApp-search.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documents-pane',
  templateUrl: './documents-pane.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documents-pane.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomAppDocumentsPaneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  navLinks = [
    {path: 'documents', label: 'Text View'},
    {path: 'grid', label: 'Grid View'},
    {path: 'customApp-search', label: 'Search Terms'},
  ]
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
import { CustomAppDetailComponent } from './customApp/customApp-detail.component';
import { CustomAppBaseComponent } from './customApp/documents-pane/customApp-base/customApp-base.component';
import { CustomAppDocumentsComponent } from './customApp/documents-pane/documents/documents.component';
import { CustomAppGridComponent } from './customApp/documents-pane/grid/grid.component'
import { CustomAppSearchComponent } from './customApp/documents-pane/customApp-search/customApp-search.component'
...

...
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'customApp',
    component: CustomAppDetailComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CustomAppBaseComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'customApp-base',
        component: CustomAppBaseComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'documents',
        component: CustomAppDocumentsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'grid',
        component: CustomAppGridComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'customApp-search',
        component: CustomAppSearchComponent,
      },
    ]
  }
...
```

**documents.component.html**

```
<div style='float: left; width: 75%;'>
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="testEntryOption">
    <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="opt1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="opt2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="opt3">Option 3</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="material-radio" value="opt4" [checked]="true">Option 4</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>

<div style='float: left; width: 25%;'>
  <mat-button-toggle-group name="buttonSelection">
    <mat-button-toggle value="button1">Button 1</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="button2">Button 2</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
<div>
  documents works!
</div>
```

I have tried several other code implementations, even a bootstrap menu bar, with no luck.  Any input is greatly appreciated.  What are my options?

Comment: remove skipLocationChange and check

Comment: @Chellappan Thanks, but it did not make a change, other than you could see where the page was in the URL box of the browser. :D

Comment: OK, I finally had a chance to look at the Chrome console, and saw an error about form items.  I think I need to get some formName stuff going in my documents.component.ts file.  Anyone have any insight into doing radio buttons and toggle buttons in Agular 6?